# Function (defined by user) as argument of a function

Tags: r, function

I would like to write a function where one of the argument is a function written by the user.

Specifically, I have something like:

```
My_function(n,g){
    x<-dnorm(n,0,1)
    y<-g(x)
    return(y)
}
```

For example, g(x)=x^2 ... but is chosen by the user. Of course, I could directly put g(dnorm(n,0,1)) as argument but I would like the user to write it in terms of x, i.e. g<-x^2 in the example.

How could I do this since the x object is only defined within the function (and not in the arguments)

I can't define the g function beforehand (otherwise, I reckon it's easy). It has to be defined within "My_function" so that the user defines everything he needs in one line.

Comment: Why not `g <- function(x) x^2`, and a correct function definition `My_function <- function(n,g) {...}`? A function can be passed as an argument to another function, since it is just another object in R (think of how we pass `mean` or `sum` to `aggregate`

Comment: Did you check out how functions are declared in `R` ? 
http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html

Comment: Your code looks fine, you can also use `'...'` to pass further arguments to the `g` function. Declare it simply like: `My_function <- function(n,g, ...) g(dnorm(n,0,1), ...)` then you can call for instance `My_function(10, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`. This will also accept any user defined lambda function like `My_function(10, function(x) 2*x)`

Comment: As I said, I would like the function to work for "any" function g(x) which the user defines within the argument of the function as g(x) and not g(dnorm(n,0,1)) 

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just declare `g` as a function with argument?

```
g=function(x) x^2

My_function=function(n,g){
    x<-dnorm(n,0,1)
    y<-g(x)
    return(y)
}

My_function(1,g)
```

Comment: Because I want everything to work in one line once the function is defined.
Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Jack4280 What's the problem with that? `My_function(10, function(x) 1/exp(x))`